# Algorithmic Graph Theory - perfect matching in bipartite graph when det(A) is not 0

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

While learning about graphs, I came across theorem that I don't quite understand, and can't find a proof.

**If G is bipartite, and $\det(A) \neq 0,$ then G has a perfect matching. (Given that matrix representation of G is A)**

Ps.:
I found bits of information, that proof may be connected with Edmonds Theorem, which I cannot find, since Edmonds-Karp Algorithm is way more popular in google ;)

Comment: Do you mean bipartite by chance?

Comment: Do you mean "bipartite?"

Comment: thats exactly what I meant, I corrected this typo ;)

Comment: It's the next-to-last letter we are asking about.

Comment: Yes, that's the one where vertices can be divided into two disjoint and independent sets.

Answer (score 2):

Let the vertices be $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}.$  The theorem follows from the definition of determinant: $$\det{A}=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^\sigma a_{i\sigma(i)}$$ where $S_n$ is the set of at permutations on $[n].$  Since $a_{ij}$ is $0$ or $1$, there must be a permutation $\sigma$ such that $i$ and $\sigma(i)$ are adjacent for $i\in [n].$

Since $\sigma$ is a bijection, the two bipartition sets have the same cardinality, and the restriction of $\sigma$ to one of them gives a perfect matching.

Comment: Is this proof from the Edmonds Theorem?

Comment: Edmonds had a number of theorems.  The one I've heard called "Edmonds Theorem" has to do with [packing of arborecences](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse522/04au/notes/lect15.pdf), so nothing to do with this.